# running android_tutorial_pubsub

Tags: ros, rosjava, android, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed and can run android_tutorial_pubsub on my 2.3.3 Droid2. I am not able, however, to view the outgoing /chatter topic after running "rostopic list" on my computer.

Both the computer and the device are on the same network and can ping each other. Currently, I have the roscore running on the computer with the ROS_MASTER_URI set to the ip address of the computer + the 11311 port and I have the entered the computer's ip address "http://192.168.*.*:11311/" into text view on the android_tutorial_pubsub app.

Is the app running its own roscore? Do i need to use a different ip address somewhere?
This seems like something that should just "work."

Any comments or suggestions would be very helpful and welcome.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12771/running-android_tutorial_pubsub/) by [Srogacki](https://answers.ros.org/users/1660/srogacki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2012-01-26

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are right. The app is in deed running its own roscore and ignoring what you configured in the master chooser dialog. We are working on that. For now you can apply [this patch](http://ias.in.tum.de/%7Emoesenle/android_tutorial_pubsub.patch) to connect to a core on your computer.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Srogacki](https://answers.ros.org/users/1660/srogacki/) on 2012-01-30**:
i made the change, but I am still not able to connect the phone to the roscore. I can ping in both directions but the /chatter topic isn't making its way to the roscore. Any further suggestions would be welcome.

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-01-27**:
It's probably the patch. Instead of using getHostName() when building the NodeConfiguration, use getHostAddress().

**Comment by [Srogacki](https://answers.ros.org/users/1660/srogacki/) on 2012-01-27**:
I am currently inputting the roscore's uri as http://192.168.9.9:11311 do I need to use a name like http://mycomputer:11311 and then give the device a host file?

**Comment by [Srogacki](https://answers.ros.org/users/1660/srogacki/) on 2012-01-27**:
Neither the node nor the topic are connected to the roscore, so the problem is either in my network, the ros_master_uri variable that I am using, or the app. I have confidence in the app and I have tried this on 3 different networks, so I guess it might be an issue with my text input into the app

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-01-26**:
Which error are you getting? Does `rosnode list` show your android node? Does `rostopic list` show the topic? If yes, what's the output of `rostopic info chatter`?

**Comment by [Srogacki](https://answers.ros.org/users/1660/srogacki/) on 2012-01-26**:
Thank you for the help. I was able to apply the patch. I had to do it manually, but it all worked out. I see how it was changed to use the roscore on the computer pending the address entered into the text box. I am still not getting connectivity between the device and the roscore. Any suggestions?

**Comment by [Srogacki](https://answers.ros.org/users/1660/srogacki/) on 2012-01-26**:
thanks. ill give it a try.

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-03-30**:
Also note: the gradle build might not replace the apk file, so you might need to delete that before rebuilding.